# What is the best way to solve Pollution problem on the name of God?

Tags: history, worship

In **Hindu religion** most of the time after worship of **God and Goddess** we throw the waste material, pictures in river and these things become a cause of pollution some time that like we are insulting God Please suggest some better ways for it.

*Please click on this link and watch this video to know what's happening*
[watch the video](https://www.facebook.com/vishku.bharat/videos/t.100000313023558/1136224746397949/?type=2&theater)

Comment: Good question. Mother Ganga as well as other rivers are being insulted by the pollution being done. We would hesitate to make a polluted offering to a murti, but no one hesitates to put a item that is not bio-degradable into Mother. What good karma is generated by making an impure offering?

Comment: Good question but it will lead to personal opinion answers. Stack Exchange sites don't accept Personal opinion questions.

Comment: Veda. Chant Vedic mantras such as Rudram, Purusha Shuktam, etc. Chant Sahasranamam. If you chant as a group, even better. Use three R's (Reduce, Reuse, Recycle). Use carpooling and public transport, or bicycles whenever possible. :) Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

One of five god elements is water. We pretty well know each river represents a deity and we celebrate [Pushkaram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushkaram)  to worship the river. Before taking bath we invoke holy river waters by the following mantra to remove our external & internal impurities.

> Ganga Cha Yamuna Chaiva Godavari Saraswati, Narmada Sindhu Kaveri
>   Jalesmin Sannidhim Kuru

Though industry & local municipal bodies are responsible, lets us try to understand how a person can be inspired to realize. In this ecosystem every [living creatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_legendary_creatures_in_Hindu_mythology) like humans, [animals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vahana), [plants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Sacred_trees_in_Hinduism), birds are forms of god, all of these need water to live, so we end up indirectly offering impurity to god. While it is presumed we’ve the primary understanding, we need to co relate many of our acts to its consequences for easy understanding of layman.

- Don’t excrete in river, same water will be used for abhishekam
- Don’t dump waste in river, same water will be used for sankalpam for
  puja rituals, annadanam, drinking by animals & humans.
- Don’t use soap/detergents in river, don’t leave plastic or other artificial
  products in river, it effects marine life (kurma/mascha avataras,
  other vehicles of gods)

On top of this every movable & immovable, living & lifeless are the forms of god. Hence our every act is a worship to god and should be done with utmost understanding and serenity.